# Why is 2 raised to 4 equal 10?

Tags: rust, binary, bitwise-operators, exponentiation

I was looking into bitwise operators in rust, and I found that

```
println!("{:X}", 1 << 4);
```

prints out 10, but 2^4 should equal 16.

Further experimentation, using powers:

```
let base: i32 = 2;
for i in 1..=5 {
    print!("{:X} ", base.pow(i));
}
```

will print out
`2 4 8 10 20` when it should print out `2 4 8 16 32`

Just wondering if you can point me out to anything in the Rust docs that highlights why binary in Rust works like this? And what can I use to do 2^4 = 16?

Comment: Perhaps it’s in base 16? Sixteen is 10 in that system, thirty-two is 20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{:X}` print numbers in hexadecimal.
So it prints 10 in base 16 which is 16, the expected answer.

To get the expected result change `{:X}` to `{}`.

Comment: Thank you so much, did not realize the hex specifier did this!